# Shopify Cart - total compare-at-price

Tags: shopify, cart

I want use the compare-at-price for wholesale pricing for a minor wholesale shop on my job.

Nevertheless, the code i'm inserting into cart below is working fine, but not taking the quantity of each item into perspective when calculating the total compare-at-price.
Right now i'm seeing the collected compare-at-price of each item, but not times the quantity.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot,
Elias

```
{% assign total_cart_item_price = 0 %}
{% assign total_cart_compare_price = 0 %}

{% for item in cart.items %} 


{% assign total_cart_item_price = total_cart_item_price | plus:   item.price %}
{% assign total_cart_compare_price = total_cart_compare_price | plus: item.variant.compare_at_price %}
{% endfor %}


<h1>Total price to be invoiced {{total_cart_compare_price | plus: item.variant.compare_at_price | money }}</h1>
<h1>Total price to be paid up front {{total_cart_item_price | money}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Now I solved it myself - if anybody need the same, here it is.

```
{% assign total_cart_item_price = 0 %}
{% assign total_cart_compare_price = 0 %}

{% for item in cart.items%} 



{% assign total_cart_item_price = total_cart_item_price | plus: item.price %}
{% assign compare_price = item.variant.compare_at_price | times: item.quantity %} 
{% assign total_cart_compare_price = total_cart_compare_price | plus: compare_price %}
{% endfor %}


<h1>Total price to be invoiced {{total_cart_compare_price | money }}</h1>
<h1>Total price to be paid up front {{total_cart_item_price | money}}</h1>
```

Comment: Include times: item.quantity in cart item price also.